# Angular 6 Input validator for 4 characters that can be combined?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have an input for 4 characters A, B, M, N . the user can enter any of these values (at least 1 and max 4, no repeated). I need a validator in case the user enter another value e.g: P or Z.

The user can combine these characters e.g.  A , BM, NA, ABMN, but not AP (the P is not valid)
any suggestion is welcome.
(I'm using angular material input field)

Attempt (this only works when I enter the first value eg. 'a' but when I enter second char it does not work anymore eg. 'ab':

```
 <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput placeholder="Cara/s" [(ngModel)]="caras_selec" name="caras" #caras="ngModel" [pattern]="[abmn]"
        minlength="1" maxlength="4">
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can you post your attempt at writing your validator?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas ok

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the negative lookahead assertion.

This allows any one of the character a,b,n or m without repetition. This implicitly takes care of max 4 characters as well. No need to explicitly mention `{1,4}` character limit

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[abnm]+$
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DkEki1/1)